# Memory leak in Chrome and difference between snapshot size and memory allocation

Tags: memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools

I am currently trying to find a memory leak in a page that receives some updates over websockets. So what I did is I checked Chrome Task Manager first and it shows that the memory allocated for tab is growing. After that I checked with timeline tool(forced GC a few times) and the memory seems to behave quite ok.
[image: Timeline]

There are some html nodes that are added(green line), so I am assuming that there are some nodes that are still referenced from js code, but then when I get to profiler(Record Heap Allocation) I see a strange behaviour - the snapshot itself is 109MB:
[image: Heap Allocation Snapshot]

But after I stop profiling memory jumps up and it's not nearly as 109MB. Examples of what I've seen:

- before snapshot 361M, after snapshot 723M, snapshot - 89M
- before snapshot 329M, after snapshot 612M, snapshot - 54.4M
- before snapshot 450M, after snapshot 773M, snapshot - 109M

I see a few nodes that are still referenced, but their Retained size is a lot smaller then the size of a snapshot.

So what I want to know is why there is such a strange behaviour in Chrome Profiler(difference of snapshot size and memory consumption) and how do I find what consumes the memory?

Answer (score 0):

That snapshot size only includes used JS heap size. Task manager will show you process total size which is a lot more than just JS heap. Also a big chunk of memory might be occupied by typed arrays which have their buffers allocated off JS heap. Can you switch from "Summary" view to "Statistics" in the heap snapshot and see what the breakdown of the js heap looks like?